Invalid provisioning profile in .NET MAUI iOS
I'm currently struggling with an issue in running MAUI app on iOS device.
First of all, the app has no errors that prevents it from running, as I have also it running on Android without any issues.
The steps the I took in order to try and run it, and also trying to resolve it:

Asked the account to create an issuer id and so got all what I've needed in order to add an individual account in Visual Studio for Mac
Added the apple developer account in Visual Studio
Created a Certificate Signing Request using Keychain Access
Using the CSR, created a certificate in my apple developer account, downloaded it and added the certificate to the Keychain access on my MacBook
Created a new provision profile in my apple developer account with the new certificate.
In Visual Studio went to apple developer accounts, and in the relevant account, downloaded all profiles.
In the main .csproj file, configured the bundle signing to the created certificate and the created provisioning profile

When trying to run, everything compiles just fine, but when getting to deployment to the device getting an error:
ApplicationVerificationFailed: Failed to verify code signature of /var/installd/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.H3ngrg/extracted/EyeSightInstaller.app : 0xe8008015 (A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found.)
I have already updated Xcode to 16.1
Visual Studio for Mac 17.6.14 (build 413)
macOS Sequoia 15.1.1
I've tried creating again and again different certificates, profiles and various combinations of the certificates, profiles, automatic and manual provisioning

First try to create an xcode project with same bundle name as you app and try to deploy it to your device.... If any thing wrong with the provisioning profile it will throw an error, and it's easy to know more details from xcode.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Not sure if this solution will for everyone, but I got it running and working so if anyone finding it, try this solution (only if there is Entitlements.plist file in your project):

Clear everything in your Entitlements.plist file and have there only the header and empty dictionary

header...

<dict></dict>


Set the provisioning to manual
Choose Automatic signing identity
Choose Automatic provisioning profile
Run the app, it should work now.
After the app installed and launched, revert the Entitlements.plist to what it had and what you need to have for your project
Without uninstalling the app from the device and without cleaning the build, run it again, as said - it should work now.

Basically, looks like for the initial install, if there is a requirement for the Entitlement.plist file, we need to empty it and revert it only after the initial install and run.
